# My map hide all the screen bounds and hides the navigation bar

Tags: ios, dictionary

i have to display a map, when doing so, the map is displayed on all the screen, it reaches all bounds and hides my navigation bar, my relevant code is this :

```
- (void)loadView {
    [self setMapView:[[[RMMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 70, 70)]autorelease]];

    [mapView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    self.view = mapView;


}
```

Please, if you need any screenshots or other code snippets, just comment me, thanx in advance for any help :)

**EDIT :**
Fishek, i have resolved my problem partially, now the map is dislayed and hiding a small part at the left of the navigation bar, here is a screenshot of my problem :

[image]

Comment: Hi Vijay, i have edited my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem is totally resolved, i have removed the `initWithFrame` method so it just `[self setMapView:[[RMMapView alloc]autorelease]];`
my code is this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [RMMapView class];
    [self setMapView:[[RMMapView alloc]autorelease]];
    [mapView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```